# Bloomberg dataservices session won't start

Tags: python, bloomberg

I do not have BBG *terminal* privileges, but I DO have an account with access  to *Data Services*. I've successfully installed blpapi, tia and the **SSH**. Using code from https://github.com/msitt/blpapi-python/tree/master/examples, these 4 lines run in the anaconda console:

```
options = blpapi.SessionOptions()

options.setServerHost('localhost')

options.setServerPort(8194)

session = blpapi.Session(options)

session.start()
Out[12]: False
```

It seems the code is installed correctly. What are the possible reasons the session wont start?

Environment: Win 7, Python 3.7, Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any process running on local machine and listening on port 8194? Normally, you will need the local process bbcomm.exe running locally and listening on port 8194.